# How to repair .mdf file?

Tags: sql-server, restore

My sql databases in SQL Server 2014 has the status "suspend" as I saw in SQL Management Studio. I can't restore to serviceable condition sql databases through standard procedures. I need to restore .mdf file.

Comment: Do you have good backups? Or is that what you mean by standard procedures?

Comment: Is the status "suspend" or "suspect"?

Comment: What errors are there in error log ?

Answer (score 4):

I guess the problem is that the database is in **suspect** mode, not **suspend**

First of all, it's not recommended to detach it, if you do that, most probably all you're left with is a third party tool, such as [ApexSQL Recover](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_recover.aspx) that can read the MDF file to recover the table records. Use the *Recover from a corrupted database or a detached MDF file* option

While the database is still attached to SQL Server, you can try the steps suggested by Paul Randal - use the emergency mode, switch to the single user mode, and try with ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG and DBCC CHECKDB

You have detailed explanation here:

[Creating, detaching, re-attaching, and fixing a SUSPECT database](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database/)

[EMERGENCY-mode repair: the very, very last resort](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-emergency-mode-repair-the-very-very-last-resort/)

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*